# Vue in DEV mode in production environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Version**
2.5.13

**Link to the source code**
https://jsfiddle.net/esrgxLfu/

**Description**
I have a PHP application which uses Vue JS mainly for the settings page. All of settings is created with Vue and we use Webpack. Everything works fine and when we are in the live version there is no console error about Vue being in development mode. We use Vue also for only one component on the dashboard page. It is a Vue TODO list like the one in the Vue documentation. On the dashboard page, we get the console message that Vue is in development mode. We use same Webpack for dashboard and settings page hence the same settings.
I have looked for hours to try to find an answer but I have not been successful which is why I am creating this issue.

In the php file we have this to place the vue component in:

`<div id="vue-tasks"></div>`

and then we included the javascript file plus the variables.

You can see everything that's being used in the fiddle but I really don't think I can make this reproducible, I'm sorry if you cannot help me with this but it is using a bunch of stuff from PHP Symfony and twig so I was not sure what I could do.

**What is expected?**
Vue to be in production mode.

**What is actually happening?**
Vue is in dev environment.

**Webpack configuration**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
         dashboard: [
            './assets/js/pages/dashboard.js' // Dashboard is the part where we have this issue and the JS is in the fiddle I provided above.
        ],
        settings: [
            './assets/js/pages/settings/main.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'images/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader','resolve-url-loader','sass-loader?sourceMap']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader','resolve-url-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                        'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'css/[name].[chunkhash].css' : 'css/[name].css'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new WebpackMd5Hash(),
        new ManifestPlugin({
            basePath: '/dist/'
        })
    ],
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            comments: false,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist' , {
            root: path.resolve(__dirname, "web"),
            verbose: true,
            dry: false
        })
    ])
}
```

Also this is the message I get in console.

> You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on
>   production mode when deploying for production. See more tips at
>   https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: I assume you've tested this by setting `NODE_ENV` to `production` and running your build script?

Comment: Yes when we build for production `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`

Comment: and have you added in something like a `console.log` to verify that your if statement for the `process.env.NODE_ENV` is being called?

Comment: It is being called because as I mentioned the settings page works correctly and is in production mode, but only dashboard page has this issue and they are using the same configuration.

Comment: What are your build scripts in package.json? Are you running something like ```npm run production``` or ```npm run dev```?

Comment: i don't think this is the issue, but have you tried `'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')` as per the docs?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are picking Vue up using a browser script tag rather than as part of a bundle from your build system.

Altering this to link to a production version of Vue will resolve the issue. In your jsfiddle, for example, replace the script link with `https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js`.